# Scheduled creation and deletion of snapshots in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have written a ***lambda function*** to create a snapshot and applied a cron job in ***Cloud Watch Events*** such that they get created everyday at 12 pm.

```
import boto3
import datetime

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event,handler):
print("\n\nAWS Snapshots starting at %s" % datetime.datetime.now())
instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[
        {'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}
    ])

for instance in instances:
    instance_name = filter(lambda tag: tag['Key'] == 'Name', instance.tags)[0]['Value']
    print("name: %s -id: %s" % (instance_name , instance.id))

    for volume in ec2.volumes.filter(Filters=[
        {'Name': 'attachment.instance-id', 'Values': [instance.id]}
    ]):
        description = 'scheduled-%s.%s-%s' % (instance_name, volume.volume_id, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))

        print 'description: %s' % (description)

    if volume.create_snapshot(VolumeId=volume.volume_id, Description=description):
        print("Snapshot created with description [%s]" % description)


print("\n\nAWS Snapshots completed at %s" % datetime.datetime.now())
return True
```

Now, all I want to do is to ***delete*** the snapshot after ***7 days*** of creation through the lambda function.And I wrote the following for that.

```
import sys
import boto3

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

try:
    days = int(sys.argv[1])
except IndexError:
    days = 7

delete_time = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=days)

print 'Deleting any snapshots older than {days} days'.format(days=days)

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

snapshots = ec2.get_all_snapshots(filters=filters)

deletion_counter = 0
size_counter = 0

for snapshot in snapshots:
    start_time = datetime.strptime(
            snapshot.start_time,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z'
    )

    if start_time < delete_time:
        print 'Deleting {id}'.format(id=snapshot.id)
        deletion_counter = deletion_counter + 1
        size_counter = size_counter + snapshot.volume_size  
        snapshot.delete(dry_run=False)

print 'Deleted {number} snapshots totalling {size} GB'.format(number=deletion_counter,size=size_counter)
```

By doing this, I get the following error :

```
module initialization error: 'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'get_all_snapshots'
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I would update your Lamdba function that creates the snapshots to add a tag to each snapshot that contains the date after which the snapshot can be deleted. You could name the tag something like: `backup-expiry-time` and the value of the tag being the date after which it can be deleted e.g. `03-11-2016`

Next I would create another Lamdba function that has the sole purpose of deleting snapshots (so that you're not creating a Lambda function that has two roles e.g. creating and deleting snapshots).

I would then use: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_snapshots

to get a list of all your snapshots that have the `backup-expiry-time` tag. Loop over this list of snapshots and delete any where the value of the `backup-expiry-time` tag shows that it can be safely deleted.

Invoke the snapshot deletion Lambda function using cron through CloudWatch in the same way that you have done for your snapshot creation function.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to add tags to those snapshots..?What change should I make to my above script?